# How to fix cascade dont work in inheritance

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

The persist method dont work in inheritance class,although I have set the property cascade in annotation (cascade="all").

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="tipo", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"menu" = "Menu", "enquete" = "Enquete"})
 */
 abstract class Widget{

   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    */
    protected $id;

 }
 /**
  * @ORM\Entity
  */
 class Enquete extends Widget{   

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Admin\Model\Alternativa", mappedBy="enquete", cascade="all")
     */
     protected $alternativas;
 }

 /**
  * @ORM\Entity
  */
 class Alternativa{       
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\Model\Enquete", inversedBy="alternativas")
     * @ORM\joinColumn(name="Enquete_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     protected $enquete;

}
```

I Use persist in cascade but dont work:

 `$enquete->addAlternativa(New Alternativa());
 $entityManager->persist($enquete);
 $entityManager->flush();`

The result is the follow error:

              `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Enquete_id' cannot be null`

Comment: Please add the code of "addAlternativa()" method also.

Comment: `cascade` expects an array not a string. You need `cascade={"all"}`

Comment: Also there's a chance you're not setting Alternativa::enquete property

Comment: Where is the $id generated, and how it is stored?

Comment: the error is in AddAlternativa()